Find the general solution of the differential equation $y'' - 7y' = t^2$
I'm struggling with this problem in my math homework. Here is what I've tried with $y'' - 7 \cdot y' = t^{2}$:
|||
|:-:|:-:|
|\begin{align*}
r^{2} - 7 \cdot r &= 0\\
r_{1} = 0 &,\, r_{2} = 7\\
y_{h} &= c_{1} \cdot e^{0 \cdot t} + c_{2} \cdot e^{7 \cdot t}\\
y_{h} &= c_{1} + c_{2} \cdot e^{7 \cdot t}\\
\end{align*}|\begin{align*}
a &= 1\\
b &= -7\\
c &= 0\\
\Delta &= 49\\
r &= \frac{7 \pm 7}{2}{:}\, r_{1} = 0,\, r_{2} = r\\
\end{align*}|
\begin{align*}
t^{2} \implies y_{p}\left( t \right) &= a \cdot t^{2} + b \cdot t + c\\
y_{p} &= a \cdot t^{2} + b \cdot t + c\\
y_{p}' &= 2 \cdot a \cdot t + b\\
y_{p}'' &= 2 \cdot a\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
y'' - 7 \cdot y' = t^{2} \implies 2 \cdot a - 7 \cdot \left( 2 \cdot a \cdot t + b \right) &= t^{2}\\
2 \cdot a - 14 \cdot a \cdot t - 7 \cdot b &= t^{2} + 0 \cdot t + 0\\
2 - 7 \cdot b &= 0\\
-14 \cdot a &= 0\\
1 &= 0\, ?\\
\end{align*}
and I've gotten stuck at the same point after multiple attempts.
My intuition says to multiply the particular by $t$ so $t^2 = at^3 + bt^2 + ct\, (+0d)$, but I don't know how to justify it mathematically. I don't know, I watched the lecture again a few times and just don't see it. I'd appreciate any help.

In addition to above comment, I believe the Laplace Transform may be a good place to look for a general way of attacking linear ODEs.

Looks good, but fyi the preferred method of showing work here is MathJax, rather than external links

Hello to Math.Se. Don't just link a picture with "I did that". handwriting can be difficult to decipher, images can have difficulty on various devices. (see here). The homework tag was "removed" for a reason (see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/homework-tag-should-be-deprecated-votings-over-you-wont- believe-what-won)). I think that it is not against the guidelines to use this in the title, but the reasons for not doing so are the same.

HINT
Why do not integrate the proposed ODE first?
\begin{align*}
y'' - 7y' = t^{2} & \Longleftrightarrow y' - 7y = \frac{t^{3}}{3} + A \Longleftrightarrow (e^{-7t}y)' = \frac{e^{-7t}t^{3}}{3} + Ae^{-7t}
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?
